# Do we need to identify the data we are using?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, integration-testing

I just completed a React component.  It calls a service in an action, and puts the result into the state in a reducer.  Then the React mechanism updates the component, and then the dom.

When I finished the component, it was checking that it was getting the values it was expecting from the service.  After several rounds of pull requests and comments, there is no particular data in the component.  The data received from the service is just kept as “data”, and it is passed to whoever needs it without examination or alteration.  Even when I pass the data to the subcomponent, I pass the whole data object using a JSX spread, and it takes the pieces it needs.

I am very uncomfortable programming this way.  If the service returns unexpected data, all I will be able to tell the business is “it broke.”  If the server is supposed to send person.arm.hand, and it sends person without an arm property, the program will throw an exception when it tries to dereference person.arm.hand.

I am told that I should rely on the integration tests.  Checks for expected values shouldn’t be put into the code.

Is that standard industry practice?